# Why Dismissible widget is not performing well?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a flutter chat application where user can delete their chat messages by horizontal swipe just like we do in Gmail application. I am using Dismissable widget of flutter for this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj243.png)

In the above picture you can see the red color box which appeared when I delete all the messages and try to send a new one.
The below is the code I am using

```
final List<ChatMessage> _message = <ChatMessage>[];

new Flexible(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true,
              itemCount: _message.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) =>
              Dismissible(
                  key: new Key("_message[index]"),
                  onDismissed: (direction){
                    _message.remove(index);

                  },
                  child: _message[index]), ),),
```

This is what the error is saying:

> I/flutter: Another exception was thrown: A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.

Comment: you have to change the state of your widget to be updated. to do that, update the _message array inside a setState, like so:
onDismissed: (direction){
setState(() {
                    _message.remove(index);});

                  },

Comment: I tried it but it is not working.

Comment: we might need more code. I couldnt reproduce the error message.

Comment: Part of your problem might be `new Key("_message[index]")` - all of your dismissables will share the same key `_message[index]`. I think you may have been wanting to do `new Key("_message[$index]")`. However, that's not going to work properly either, as when you delete a message it will simply move the text to the item earlier in the list. So what you want to do instead is use a hashcode of the string actually being shown in each message. Since you haven't posted enough of your code to show what `ChatMessage` is, I can't write a full answer - so please post more of your code =).